# MatLab: code for polynomial long division

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to write a matlab code that will divide two polynomials given in the form of a structure array such as `p=struct('exponent',{0,1,2},'coeff',{1,4,2})`.

This is what I have so far it calls another function `addPoly` which i have checked works well.

```
function [ quo,rem ] = divide3Poly( p,q )
%funtion addPoly takes two arguments representing polynomials p and q in the form of
%structure arrays and returns the representation for the polynomial p/q
%with no zero coefficients and the exponents in increasing order.

n=size(p,2);
m=size(q,2);

if p(n).exponent<q(m).exponent
    quo(1).exponent=0;
    quo(1).coeff=0;
    rem=p;
    return
end


quo=struct('exponent',{},'coeff',{});
rem=p;
x=size(rem,2);
for a=x:-1:1  %line 20
    while rem(a).exponent>=q(m).exponent
        tempquo(1).exponent=rem(a).exponent-q(m).exponent;
        tempquo(1).coeff=rem(a).coeff/q(m).coeff;
    for i=m:-1:1
        temprem(i).exponent=q(i).exponent+tempquo(1).exponent;
        temprem(i).coeff=-q(i).coeff*tempquo(1).coeff;
    end

    rem=addPoly(temprem,rem);
    quo=addPoly(quo,tempquo);

    x=size(rem,2);
    if rem(x).coeff==0
        rem=rem(1:x-1);
    end

end %this is line 37
end
end
```

The problem I am having is that I get an error saying Index exceeds matrix dimensions in line 37 and i'm not sure why.

I have tried this code without the for loop starting in line 20 and it runs without error messages although it only runs until there is one term in `quo`. For example, with `p=struct('exponent',{0,2,3},'coeff',{3,2,1})` and `q=struct('exponent',{0,1},'coeff',{1,1})` I expected to get `quo=struct('exponent',{0,1,2},'coeff',{1,1,-1})` and `rem=struct('exponent',{0},'coeff',{4})` but my code produced `quo=struct('exponent',{2},'coeff',{1})` and `rem=struct('exponent',{0,2},'coeff',{3,1})` which is still correct but it just hasn't simplified enough.

Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: The logic is somewhat complicated because of the data structure.  I recommend storing these differently: just use a single array of coefficients, where the exponents are understood, and zeros are used when the term is not present.  Then write a display function that prints the exponents and "hides" the zeros for presentation purposes.  This will greatly simplify your computation code.

Comment: Thanks, will that help the issue that it stops computing when `quo` has only one term though?

Comment: The code still won't run for other people due to external functions.  You'll have to do your own debugging.  Surely you can reduce the problem further.  Some `if` statement is exiting when you don't expect.  Well, print out the conditions and the variables for each loop through.  On each loop, is it comparing the numbers you expect?

Comment: Yes it seems to compare what I expect in the loop, the problem I face is that it only seems to complete the while loop once, but it should keep going until the conditions are no longer satisfied. I am unsure why it does this